# how does jquery knows what go is

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

[jsfiddle example found on www](http://jsfiddle.net/RPSzb/2/)

how does jquery knows what go is ?

```
$('#myDiv').animate({  textIndent: 0 }, {
    step: function(go) {
      $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotateY('+go+'deg)');
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotateY('+go+'deg)');
      $(this).css('-o-transform','rotateY('+go+'deg)');
      $(this).css('transform','rotateY('+go+'deg)');
    },
    duration: 1000,
    complete: function(){ alert('done') }
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: The first parameter of the `step` callback is the numeric value of the property being animated at each step. Because jQuery is doing the calculation, that value is available to jQuery to use when calling the callback sent to the `step` option.

Comment: The `go` tag is used for the Go programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`go` is just the name of the function's parameter. According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> **Step Function**
>
> The second version of `.animate()` provides a `step` option — a callback
>   function that is fired at each step of the animation. This function is
>   useful for enabling custom animation types or altering the animation
>   as it is occurring. It accepts two arguments (`now` and `fx`), and this is
>   set to the DOM element being animated.
>
> - `now`: the numeric value of the property being animated at each step
> - fx:
>     a reference to the `jQuery.fx` prototype object, which contains a number
>     of properties such as `elem` for the animated element, `start` and `end` for
>     the first and last value of the animated property, respectively, and
>     `prop` for the property being animated.

So `go` is just this function's name for the `now` parameter.

Comment: animating an array of variables of an element , it takes the last variable for the go function.

Comment: everone tells go is calculated by jquery but passing it as a variable to a function means it can be influenced by the coder

Comment: @wetlip I'm sorry, but I can't tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

"Step" is a specific animate option.
One of the arguments of "step" is the value the element is currently at in its animation.

When you animate something in jQuery, it steps between a start point and an end point. The bits in the middle are worked out by jQuery and passed along.

Therefore it knows what "go" is because its just a number that was created by the animation function.

Answer (score 0):

This animation is using the `textIndent` property on the square to rotate the square about the y-axis.

The `textIndent` property is defined in the CSS to start at `180px` and the animation setup will reduce the `textIndent` value to to `0`. At each step of the reduction from 180 down to 0, the value is passed into the **[`step`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step)** function as the argument for the `go` parameter. This value is then being used to rotate the square about the y-axis using CSS transforms.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `step` option allows you to define a callback function that takes two parameters and is called on each "step" of the animation.  You have defined the callback function to only take one parameter (which you've named `go`), and you have ignored the second parameter.  The callback function you created is called an `anonymous function` and you are allowed to name the parameters anything you'd like.

You can read more about it here: [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)